# Where should I put data like testimonials and addresses in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I am fairly new to Umbraco and I am wondering where I should put pieces of random data.
I have a lot of experience with Sitecore, used it for several years, I am certified etc etc. But now I have to build something with Umbraco. At a first glance Umbraco looks inferior to Sitecore in every way, but I might be wrong about that.

So what I am wondering is, where should I put non-browsable pieces of data that are visible on several places throughout the website? I'd like to create data items in Umbraco for things like Testimonials, Offices? I'd like to have a centralized place in Umbraco where they can be maintained and reference them from a page node. But the way it looks now is that everything has to be on the page node. Which is sort ok, for your average family webpage.

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: "At a first glance Umbraco looks inferior to Sitecore in every way, but I might be wrong about that." It's a different product, look at it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create another node under the man content and call it site settings and store them there that way all pages under the home page are just visible pages on the front end and all data nodes are in a separate area.

Comment: This works also! I've heard dev. saying they work like this to centralise non-browsables. What I find though is that content editors might not really know the difference between browsable and non-browsable so grouping them like this doesn't really help them so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is one property in umbraco that you can add to document types and name it "umbracoNaviHide" (for alias, the name can be anything). This allows wires in automatically to the .IsVisible() method.

```
var children = Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible());
```

I find this situation to be very frequent, think of slideshows. When I make an Umbraco website, under my root node I normalle havea Slideshow document type (that contains slides) and I programmatically traverse those to build the slideshow on the home page for example. This Slideshow document has that "umbracoNaviHide" property and I skip it from my menus either using the .IsVisible() method or by manually skipping specific document types.

```
var menuItems = Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias != "Slideshow" && x.DocumentTypeAlias != "Search");
```

On the other hand, if you are looking for "labels", you can look at "Dictionnary" items under the "Settings" tab.

To directly answer your questions, I reccomend putting non-browsable pieces of data as children of the relevant browsable content node. (But there are other valid ways to do this, it really is up to you and what's best for your content editors.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it not possible to, like in Sitecore, have a field on (to use your example) the home node that contains one or more references to the slides that you want to show up?

Comment: Absolutely, you could use the "Multi-node tree picker" data type, add a field on the home node and call it "slides" and then pick slides from the slide nodes this data type allows for ordering also).

Comment: on a side note, using content nodes for non-browsable elements is also good because if you go on multi-lingual (or worse multi-site-multi-lingual) setups, you'll want the translations / different languages to be "smooth". (Languages in Umbraco is not as powerful as in Sitecore.)